# Suddenly lost access to pfSense

Tags: pfsense

I've just installed pfSense in VMware and play around with the settings.

Suddenly, I lost access to Web GUI.

I ran `tcpdump` on it and was able to see the packet from my notebook reached to it.

What went wrong?

How do I get the access back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my answer is from [this site](https://chrislazari.com/pfsense-enabling-administration-via-the-wan-interface/)

- SSH into your Server or open terminal if you have direct access to your PFSense Server
- run `pfctl -d` to disable the package filter
- try connecting to GUI via webbrowser

I omitted the first step, because it is not needed for your case.